# How to understand `sed -n '/^#n_sns\tn_loc/,/^[^0-9]/ p' $log_file | grep -E '^[0-9]' > $log_file.sns_p_loc`?

Tags: sed

I am reading a tutorial, there is a sed command:

```
sed -n '/^#n_sns\tn_loc/,/^[^0-9]/ p' $log_file | grep -E '^[0-9]' > $log_file.sns_p_loc
```

I can not understand it, who can explain to me? or whether it is wrong in somewhere?

Comment: "whether it is wrong in somewhere"? What is that it's supposed to do for it to be wrong?

Comment: I do not have seen this `^[^0-9]`.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
sed -n '                # run sed but don't print by default
/^#n_sns\tn_loc/,       # from match 1
/^[^0-9]/               # to match 2
 p'                     # print
```

Your special question:

```
^                       # anchor at begin  of line
[                       # opens a "bracket expression" which normally matches any single character from the list
^                       # a leading ^ makes it match any single character NOT from the list.
0-9                     # character range, only digits 
]                       # close "bracket expression"
```

The `grep` seems to be redundant; its operation (print lines starting with a digit) could be done by the `sed` in the first place.

Comment: What's the meaning of `from match 1 to match 2`?

Comment: We're dealing with an address range that starts when a line matches the first regex, and stops when the second regex is matched. Lines before of after are being ignored (unless another match 1 were encountered).